# ArgumentException, TargetParameterCountException on Control.BeginInvoke(). Why?

Tags: c#, invoke, begininvoke

I am getting ArgumentException and TargetParameterCountException when using BeginInvoke().

1) In first call it gives System.ArgumentException: Object of type 'System.String' cannot be converted to type 'System.Object[]'.

2) In second call it gives Gives TargetParameterCountException: {"Parameter count mismatch."}

Why does it happen?

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BeginInvokeArgsTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private delegate void VoidDelegate(params object[] args);

        private Delegate methodDelegate;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            methodDelegate = new VoidDelegate(SetLabelDelegate);

            Thread t = new Thread(ChangeDay);
            t.Start();
        }

        private void ChangeDay()
        {
            //Gives ArgumentException. 'System.String' cannot be converted to type 'System.Object[]'.
            ChangeDay(new VoidDelegate(SetLabelDelegate), "Sunday" );

            //Gives TargetParameterCountException: {"Parameter count mismatch."}
            ChangeDay(new VoidDelegate(SetLabelDelegate), "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday");
        }


        private void ChangeDay(Delegate del, params object[] args)
        {
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                methodDelegate = del;
                this.BeginInvoke(new VoidDelegate(RouterDelegate), args );
            }
        }

        private void RouterDelegate(params object[] args)
        {
            methodDelegate.DynamicInvoke(args);
        }

        private void SetLabelDelegate(params object[] args)
        {
            foreach (object day in args)
            {
                label1.Text = day as string;
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

*PS: Corrected the wrongly framed question now. My sincere apologies for the old wrongly framed question. I am usually not this careless. Please also ignore language syntax errors if any.*

Comment: It's hard to work it out from such incomplete information. If you could provide a short but *complete* example, it would be a lot easier to work out.

Comment: Edited the question. please tell if it is complete enough now!

Comment: Not really - it's not complete, is it? It's not something I can compile, run, and see the problem...

Comment: Thank you for your patience and time. My sincere apologies for the old wrongly framed question. I am usually not this careless. I have provided correct details now.

Comment: Dear Jon, Now I have updated with a compilable source code. Yesterday I was not having access to my VS when I posted this question so had given pseudocode. Today it is complete.

Comment: Copying and pasting the code doesn't let me compile it - you're still relying on the designer. Still, with a bit of work it should be enough to work out what's going on. I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay... with a fuller example, it's reasonably easy to see what's going on.

The problem is that the delegate expects a single parameter which must be an object array.

Now look at how you're invoking it:

```
private void ChangeDay(Delegate del, params object[] args)
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        methodDelegate = del;
        this.BeginInvoke(new VoidDelegate(RouterDelegate), args);
    }
}
```

The `args` here is expected to be an array *of arguments*... multiple of them. So if your delegate took two string parameters, you'd have an `object[]` with a length of two, each of element of which would be a string reference.

So what you *want* is an `object[]` with length 1, whose sole element is a reference to another `object[]`. You can do that easily:

```
this.BeginInvoke(new VoidDelegate(RouterDelegate), new object[] { args });
```

and the same thing in `RouterDelegate`:

```
methodDelegate.DynamicInvoke(new object[] { args });
```

At that point, I believe everything will work fine (in terms of delegate invocation - you should *not* be sleeping in the UI thread, but that's a different matter).

Comment: Thanks. Using new object[] does work. +1 for that. But, why is formal parameter not self-sufficient to represent an array of objects and needs a further conversion to new object[]? 

And, if I understood your point correctly, you have also mentioned  that passing more than one string would work with earlier code(without using new object[]). But for me it gives TargetParameterCountException!

Comment: @RealRed.: You need to build an array which contains one value per parameter. Currently you're not doing that - you're passing in the `object[]` (which is *just* the first argument) as if it's *all* the arguments. You may find it easier to understand all of this if you take out the `params` and consider a delegate which takes (say) an `int` and a `string`. Experiment with that and I think you'll see why the wrapping is necessary. You've given yourself a confusing example :)